# Draw a Fibonacci series of squares!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fibonacci

#### Introduction

To draw a Fibonacci series of square, you start by drawing a one-unit square:

```
 _
|_|
```

Then another one to the left:

```
 _ _
|_|_|
```

Then a two-unit one on top:

```
 _ _
|   |
|_ _|
|_|_|
```

Then a three-unit one on the right:

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|   |     |
|_ _|     |
|_|_|_ _ _|
```

Then a five-unit one on the bottom:

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|   |     |
|_ _|     |
|_|_|_ _ _|
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|_ _ _ _ _|
```

etc.

#### Your task

Given *N* squares to print (0 <= *N* <= 20), print the figure that contains *N* squares. For example, if *N* was 4, it should print:

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|   |     |
|_ _|     |
|_|_|_ _ _|
```

<sub>Note that it does not have to exactly follow this format, just something that represents the same figure.</sub>

Since it has four squares in it:

```
     3
    _v_ _ _ _
   |   |     |
   |_ _|     |< 4
2 >|_|_|_ _ _|
      ^
      1
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1697 1087"><title>Fibonacci Folge</title><desc>16 Zahlen der Fibonacci Folge</desc><defs><view id="fibo14" viewBox="50 50 610 377" /><view id="fibo12" viewBox="427 283 233 144" /><view id="fibo10" viewBox="427 283 89 55" /><view id="fibo8" viewBox="482 317 34 21" /><view id="fibo6" viewBox="482 317 13 8" /><view id="fibo4" viewBox="490 322 5 3" /></defs><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo14" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 14"><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo12" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 12"><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo10" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 10"><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo8" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 8"><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo6" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 6"><a xlink:href="fibonacci.svg#fibo4" xlink:title="Fibonacci Folge 4"><rect x="491" y="322" width="1" height="1" fill="#dddd88" /><rect x="490" y="322" width="1" height="1" fill="#dddddd" /><rect x="490" y="323" width="2" height="2" fill="#eeee99" /><rect x="492" y="322" width="3" height="3" fill="#eeeeee" /></a><rect x="490" y="317" width="5" height="5" fill="#cccc77" /><rect x="482" y="317" width="8" height="8" fill="#cccccc" /></a><rect x="482" y="325" width="13" height="13" fill="#dddd88" /><rect x="495" y="317" width="21" height="21" fill="#dddddd" /></a><rect x="482" y="283" width="34" height="34" fill="#eeee99" /><rect x="427" y="283" width="55" height="55" fill="#eeeeee" /></a><rect x="427" y="338" width="89" height="89" fill="#cccc77" /><rect x="516" y="283" width="144" height="144" fill="#cccccc" /></a><rect x="427" y="50" width="233" height="233" fill="#dddd88" /><rect x="50" y="50" width="377" height="377" fill="#dddddd" /></a><rect x="50" y="427" width="610" height="610" fill="#eeee99" /><rect x="660" y="50" width="987" height="987" fill="#eeeeee" /><g font-family="Arial" text-anchor="middle"><text x="505" y="327" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="0.7rem">21</text><text x="499" y="300" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="0.9rem">34</text><text x="455" y="310" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="1.2rem">55</text><g font-size="2.0rem"><text x="471" y="382" dominant-baseline="middle">89</text><text x="588" y="355" dominant-baseline="middle">144</text><text x="543" y="166" dominant-baseline="middle">233</text><text x="239" y="239" dominant-baseline="middle">377</text><text x="355" y="732" dominant-baseline="middle">610</text><text x="1153" y="543" dominant-baseline="middle">987</text></g></g><path d="M1647 50 a987,987 0 0,1 -987,987 a610,610 0 0,1 -610,-610 a377,377 0 0,1 377,-377 a233,233 0 0,1 233,233 a144,144 0 0,1 -144,144 a89,89 0 0,1 -89,-89 a55,55 0 0,1 55,-55 a34,34 0 0,1 34,34 a21,21 0 0,1 -21,21 a13,13 0 0,1 -13,-13 a8,8 0 0,1 8,-8 a5,5 0 0,1 5,5 a3,3 0 0,1 -3,3 a2,2 0 0,1 -2,-2 a1,1 0 0,1 1,-1 a1,1 0 0,1 1,1" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25" fill="none" /></svg>
```

Comment: Oliver I have added a SVG as snippet to visualize your post. If it is not helpful please delete it

Comment: Up to F(50), really? That would be ~12.5 billion character wide.

Comment: @Arnauld You're right. I have updated it to up to 20.

Comment: Does the output have to follow the [cumbersome I/O formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/60043) (i.e. is this an ASCII art challenge?), or could it use built-in graphics?

Comment: @JHM I have updated the question.

Comment: "highly discouraged" doesn't mean anything - builtins are either allowed or not. You also don't state *which* builtins you mean - just Fibonacci square drawing builtins? Fibonacci builtins in general? And *it does not have to exactly follow this format, just something that represents the same figure* isn't really descriptive. You need to be more precise about exactly what is valid and what isn't. Once again, the Sandbox could've helped you work out problems before posting this to main. 5 hours is not nearly enough time in the Sandbox to get feedback.

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53369/fibonacci-spiral)

Comment: Please exclude the `N=0` case since it almost certainly has to be handled as an (uninteresting) exception

Comment: Would `OOOOOO\nO  OOO\nO  O O\nOOOOOO\n` (replace `\n` by real newlines) be a valid result for the n=4 case ? Different orientation, no attempt to use nice box characters. (It can be converted to the example format by replaceing each `O` by `_|` and replacing spurious characters, but that takes quite a bit of code)

Comment: Even `N=20` is quite high. It gives a solution of about 150 million characters with the suggested output format. Possibly  lower the limit even more.

Comment: Is it OK for the spiral as a whole to turn left instead of right ?