# Ascii Fibonacci spiral

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fibonacci

Let's continue the [fibonacci](/questions/tagged/fibonacci) based challenges stream, here's the next one:

### Task

Draw a Fibonacci spiral [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) of n segments where starting from the first term:

- each nth segment has a length of nth Fibonacci term.
- each segment is joined to the end of the previous, rotated by 90 degrees  taking the end of previous segment as center of rotation.
- you can choose any printable ascii character chars to draw the spiral with, although the background must be spaces.
- You can draw the spiral in any orientation and turning clockwise or counterclockwise
- Leading/trailing whitespace is allowed within reason

### Example

Let's explain it with the help of a visual example:
Beginning of segments are highlighted with an arrow character (> < ^ v) to indicate the direction.
End of segments highlighted with `o` to indicate the pivot for the rotation of next segment.

Taking the first 9 terms [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21] (the first term(0) doesn't draw anything) we draw clockwise.

```
o###################<o
                     #
                     #
                     #
                     #
                     #
                     #
                     #
             o#<o    #
             v  ^    #
             # oo    #
             #       #
             #       ^
             o>######o
```

As you can see we start with one character(a segment of length 1) then add one to the right, then add two by rotating 90 degrees, then 3, then 5 .. and so on.

You can choose 0 or 1 indexing in the Fibonacci sequence, f(0) can draw anything or a single character, just be consistent on this.

## Some more examples

n==1 (0-indexed) or n==0 (1-indexed)-> [1]

```
*
```

n==2 -> [1,1]

```
2     1          or 21
1  or 2  or 12
```

here we used '1' for the first segment and '2' for the second

n==3 ->[1,1,2]

```
1     or 12  or...
233       3
          3
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): all the usual golfing rules apply.
- Either a function or a full program is fine.
- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53369/84844)

Comment: A few test cases would be needed, to know exactly where each segment ends or how it is joined to the previous one (first turn, then join it seems)

Comment: Also, is it ok if the program fails for large inputs (or not so large) due to floating point precision errors?

Comment: Please also clarify if the output can be rotated so that the _last_ segment is always in the same direction

Comment: @Luis Mendo edited but left closed, big fault not using the sandbox! I thought it was so simple to explain but it wasn't actually. Hope it's clear now. About the floating point errors I'm gonna say no, since it's a integer sequence and ascii-art I don't see any reason to allow imprecisions. Would you like to clarify why I may allow it please?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I hope it gets reopened soon (only one vote left). My question about floating-point precision was because of [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression). But I agree that it seems better not to allow floating-point errors, as the challenge can be done using only integers

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 25 bytes

```
TF0i:"P!1bYs:Q1&(3MPw]Zc&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8TNINNKKUDRMCmy2CrQUE3D2DegPDYqWe3/f3MA)

#### Explanation

```
TF     % Push [1, 0]. This array will contain the two most recent Fibonacci
       % numbers in each iteration k: [f(k), f(k-1)] 
0      % Push 0. This initiallizes the matrix M that will be used as output
i:"    % Input n. Do the following n times
  P!   %   Flip vertically, transpose. This rotates tmatrix M by 90 degrees
  1    %   Push 1 (*)
  b    %   Bubble up: moves the array [f(k), f(k-1)] to the top of the stack
  Ys   %   Cumulative sum: gives [f(k), f(k+1)]
  :    %   Range (uses first entry): [1, 2, ..., f(k)]
  Q    %   Add 1, element-wise: gives [2, 3, ..., f(k)+1] (**)
  1    %   Push 1 (***)
  &(   %   Write 1 (*) in M at the rows given by (**) and column 1 (***).
       %   This extends M with the new segment of the spiral, padding with 0
  3M   %   Push [f(n), f(n+1)] again
  P    %   Flip: gives [f(n+1), f(n)], ready for the next iteration
  w    %   Swap: moves the extended M to the top of the stack
]      % End
Zc     % Convert values 1 in M into char '#', and 0 to space
&      % Set alternative input/output spec for the next function, which is
       % implicit display. This causes the function to use only one input,
       % which means that only the top of the stack is displayed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 99 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:' #'[2*n:]or[k:='#'+''.join(l[1:])for l in zip(*f(n-1)[::-1])]+(k:=len(k)-1)*['#'+' '*k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvBCsIwDADQXwnskKRjQvWgBPYlpYeNWaytaSm76M/X4cHrg1ff@6Po5VZb72HOy2vdFlBBGNCdjYovzSWZccAR8fQsUSk7K55DaZAhKnxiJRNIJ8tOZLKe/UhHyXelxIca99uAJvn@b4GuLLVF3Slz/wI)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LÅf0ŽPjSΛ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvQFZwedm//9vCQA)

0-based and the spiral goes counterclockwise starting towards the left, similar as the example in the challenge.
Input \$n=0\$ will always draw a single character instead of an empty output.
Draws with character `0`, but this could alternatively be [any other digit](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmuXRvRb@wedm//9vAQA), [the lowercase alphabet](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmuPRvRb@wedm//9vAQA), [the input digits](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmufRvRb@wedm//9vaAQA), [the digits of the 0-based \$n^{th}\$ Fibonacci number](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrWtTRvRb@wedm//9vaAQA), etc. by replacing the `0`.
The start and direction of the spiral can also be changed by replacing `ŽPjS` with [`Ž8O` for right counterclockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvRb@wedm//9vCQA); [`ŽG~S` for down counterclockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRve51wedm//9vCQA); [`ŽNāS` for left clockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvX5HGoPPzf7/3xIA); [`Ƶ‘0š` for up clockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsGxrY8aZhgcXXhu9v//lgA); [`Ž9¦S` for right clockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvZaHlgWfm/3/vyUA); or [`ŽICS` for down clockwise](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvZ7Owedm//9vCQA) ([up counterclockwise is the only one that's a byte longer with `Ž2„0š`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53BrmsHRvUaPGuYZHF14bvb//5YA)).

**Explanation:**

```python
L          # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 Åf        # Get the (0-based) n'th Fibonacci number for each of these values
   0       # Push character "0"
    ŽPj    # Push compressed integer 6420
       S   # Pop and convert it to a list of digits: [6,4,2,0]
        Λ  # Use the Canvas builtin with these three arguments
           # (which is output immediately afterwards implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ŽPj` is `6420`.

As for some additional information about the Canvas builtin `Λ`:
It takes 3 arguments to draw an ASCII shape:

1. Length of the lines we want to draw
2. Character/string to draw
3. The direction to draw in, where each digit represents a certain direction:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

`LÅf0Ž8OS` creates the following Canvas arguments:

1. Length: the first input amount of 1-based Fibonacci numbers
2. Character: `"0"`
3. Directions: `[6,4,2,0]`, which translates to \$[←,↓,→,↑]\$

Step 1: Draw 1 characters (`"0"`) in direction 6/`←`:

```python
0
```

Step 2: Draw 1-1 characters (`""`) in direction 4/`↓`:

```python
0
```

Step 3: Draw 2-1 characters (`"0"`) in direction 2/`→`:

```python
00
```

Step 4: Draw 3-1 characters (`"00"`) in direction 0/`↑`:

```python
 0
 0
00
```

Step 5: Draw 5-1 characters (`"000"`) in direction 6/`←`:

```python
00000
    0
   00
```

Step 6: Draw 8-1 characters (`"0000000"`) in direction 4/`↓`:

```python
00000
0   0
0  00
0
0
0
0
0
```

etc.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for an in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
０１⁸┤［┌┌＋｝）Ｈ#×２１╋↶
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjEwJXVGRjExJXUyMDc4JXUyNTI0JXVGRjNCJXUyNTBDJXUyNTBDJXVGRjBCJXVGRjVEJXVGRjA5JXVGRjI4JTIzJUQ3JXVGRjEyJXVGRjExJXUyNTRCJXUyMUI2,i=OQ__,v=8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
×3ʀd⁰ɽ∆f›ø∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDlzPKgGTigbDJveKIhmbigLrDuOKIpyIsIiIsIjciXQ==)

*-1 byte thanks to emanresu A*

Comment: [-1](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDlzPKgGTigbDJveKIhmbigLrDuOKIpyIsIiIsIjciXQ==) and fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22*? 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆḞ€R¬W€1¦t⁶;ɗ€0¦Ṛz⁶ʋ/ZṚ$⁸¡Y
```

A full program that accepts an integer and prints a spiral using `1`s.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Md8x41rQk6tCYcSBkeWlbyqHGb9cnpQI7BoWUPd86qAvJPdetHAZkqjxp3HFoY@f//fzMA)**

#### How?

```
ÆḞ€R¬W€1¦t⁶;ɗ€0¦Ṛz⁶ʋ/ZṚ$⁸¡Y - Main Link: integer, N
ÆḞ€                         - first N Fibbonacci numbers
   R                        - range       -> [[1],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],...]
    ¬                       - logical NOT -> [[0],[0],[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],...]
     W€1¦                   - wrap the first one
                   ʋ/       - reduce by - f(Current, Next):
            ɗ€0¦            -   apply to the final entry of Current:
         t⁶;                -     trim spaces and concatenate Next
                Ṛ           -     reverse
                 z⁶         -     transpose with spaces
                       $⁸¡  - repeat N times:
                     Z      -   transpose
                      Ṛ     -   reverse
                          Y - join with newline characters
                            - implicit print
```

---

* Awaiting clarification on whether "output can be rotated so that the last segment is always in the same direction" - [22](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Md8x41rQk6tCYcSBkeWlbyqHGb9cnpQI7BoWUPd86qAvJPdetH/v//3wIA):

```
ÆḞ€R¬W€1¦t⁶;ɗ€0¦Ṛz⁶ʋ/Y
```

Comment: This seems to use a fixed _ending_ direction, instead of a fixed starting one as the challenge seems to require. I was considering doing the same, so I've asked for clarification

Comment: @LuisMendo I thought our choice under "Start rotating from left ,right,up or down as your wish." didn't need to be consistent across inputs ...hmm.

Comment: @LuisMendo put in a version that has a fixed starting direction for now.

Comment: Updated the question and your 22Byte answer should be fine

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
⊞υ¹ＦＮ«⌈υ↶⊞υΣ…⮌υ²»¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1RHwVDTmistv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLM6AoM69EwzexIjO3NFejVBOokjMgsyy/xCc1rUQDzIMaEgyUd65Mzkl1zsgv0AhKLUstKk4F6tBRMNIEaav9/9/yv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
⌈υ
```

Output the latest Fibonacci number in unary.

```
↶
```

Rotate ready for the next Fibonacci number.

```
⊞υΣ…⮌υ²
```

Calculate the next Fibonacci number.

```
»¹
```

Print a final character (this is because Charcoal is actually drawing the lines a character early, so it's drawing `1, 2, 3, 5, 8...` and the second `1` is missing).

It's possible to draw the lines according to the specification by rotating for the last character of the line, but in this case the spiral has to be drawn clockwise instead:

```
⊞υ¹ＦＮ«¶⌈υ¶↷⊞υΣ✂υ±²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1RHwVDTmistv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLM6AoM69EQykmTwmoBsrzTazIzC3N1SjVRIjBVWSW5ZcEZaZnlGiAuVAbgoHKg3Myk1NBHL/U9MSSVA0jTZD@2v//Lf/rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
¶⌈υ¶
```

Output the latest Fibonacci number in unary, but positioned rotated from the end of the previous one.

```
↷
```

Rotate ready for the next Fibonacci number.

```
⊞υΣ✂υ±²
```

Calculate the next Fibonacci number, but repeating the initial `1` the first time.

Comment: It seems to skip the first term or the second, they are both 1

Comment: @AZTECCO Actually according to Charcoal's drawing approach I was skipping the very last character, but of course your example didn't show that so I hadn't realised my mistake. I've added it in and also come up with an alternative approach which follows your method more closely (except it now has to do it in a different direction).

Comment: Neil I'm sorry for the discomfort, yes adding a character at the end would be fine. Your answer works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 326 bytes:

```
R=range
f=lambda n,a=1,b=1:[b]+f(n-1,b,a+b)if n else[]
def g(b,e,x,y,q,w):
 if e:x+=q;y+=w;b[x][y]=1;return g(b,e-1,x,y,q,w)
 return x,y
def d(b,r,x,y,c=1):
 if r:d(b,r,*g(b,r.pop(),x,y,0+c%2*[1,-1][c%4==1],0+(c%2==0)*[-1,1][c%4==2]),c+1)
def F(n):
 r=f(n);b=[[0 for _ in R(r[-2]+1)]for _ in R(r[-1])];d(b,r,len(b),0);return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BboMwEETP5St8iWRjU2HaQwTaaz4gV2tVYTAJEjXEpQp8PV0gHHrcmTezu8M83nv/cR7CslwhlP7moga68tvWJfOqBK0s6NxYlA33CU2qlFa0DfPMdT/OYFS7ht24VU5NalYP9RR5xAhw@SThUcwSnoU1E5oZQRfBjb/B7wGqOyIRexkkbI01AWGzK9CvxpDvarymw/vQD1xsSCqrUxYbrRKNpjp9AmgkkZMKkIrY0KbDyVCoSmqxbblwv3YHoOdEYcGYlDV9YF@s9ezKg0kyJBb/axoFFvspnfPcCpWK4zG7rGy7shd@pvK3IbR@5K1Y/gA)

Comment: It seems it doesn't work properly for the first few terms

Comment: @AZTECCO Can you clarify, the spiral generated for terms 1 to 3 matches your posted output.

Comment: Ajax your answer prints nothing for 0 and may be fine, but still prints nothing for 1 and that would be fine if you 1-index in [0,1,1,...], for 2 seems to print a [1,2] spiral skipping one term, and seems to start from 2nd term for any input(e.g. [1,2,3,5..]. Anyway I updated the question and hopefully it's going to be reopened, check it out and if you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask clarifications